# how to use vuetify text opacity with coloured text

Tags: vuetify.js

The default opacity for text in Vuetify seems to be `text-medium-emphasis`. When using coloured text, this is (IMHO) too faint.
There is a class `text-high-emphasis` but this appears to override the colour, so the text becomes black (or dark grey), High-emphasis doesn't appear to change anything anyway, even in black.

```
<v-chip  v-else-if="chip.distance===0"  size="x-large"  variant="outlined"  class="font-weight-bold text-high-emphasis"
        :color="colourFromDistance(r,c)"
        > {{ chip.name }} 
</v-chip>
```

demo codepen [here](https://codepen.io/quilkin/pen/WNKmqLz)

Is it possible to have 'stronger' (high-emphasis) coloured text?

Comment: medium is not the default, high is, as is stated here in the [docs](https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/text-and-typography/#opacity).  Maybe the default red, `#F44336`, is too light for you.  You can override with a darker red that may stand out better.

Comment: Thank you, I missed that. But it's still the case that setting a opacity overrides thecolour.